# Returning number from bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
byte_swap () {
# Take "abcdefgh" and return it as "ghefcdab"
echo "${1:6:2}${1:4:2}${1:2:2}${1:0:2}"
}

crmagic_hex="4372 3234" # Cr24
version_hex="0200 0000" # 2
pub_len_hex=$(byte_swap $(printf '%08x\n' $(ls -l "$pub" | awk '{print $5}')))
sig_len_hex=$(byte_swap $(printf '%08x\n' $(ls -l "$sig" | awk '{print $5}')))
(
 echo "$crmagic_hex $version_hex $pub_len_hex $sig_len_hex" | xxd -r -p
 cat "$pub" "$sig" "$zip"
) > "$crx"
```

But when executing:

```
 ./crxmake.sh: line 49: printf: Users: invalid number 
 ./crxmake.sh: line 50: printf: Users: invalid number
```

This is used to produce a crx file for the chrom plugin.

Comment: Your `$(ls ...)` pipeline isn't returning what you expect. It is returning `Users` possibly among other things and `Users` isn't a valid number. This is part of why you shouldn't [parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `stat` or similar instead.

Comment: As mentioned above: try `stat -c "%s" "$pub"` instead of `ls -l "$pub"`.